# How are modules are installed and located?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I need help to troubleshoot the installation of [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) for an GAE app.

On my Windows PC, I have python.exe in `C:\python27`.

I installed gspread by running its `setup.py` from its distribution folder as follows:

```
c:\python27\python.exe setup.py install --home=X
```

The following folder and files were created in `X\lib\python`:

```
request-2.9.1-py2.7.egg (a folder)
easy-install.pth
gspread-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
site.py
```

Why `lib\python`?  Is this sub-folder hardcoded somewhere?

When I launch my Python interpreter, I can then `import gspread`. `sys.path` includes the fully qualified path to `X\lib\python\gspread-0.2.5-py2.7.egg`.  Note it's a path to a file and not a folder.

How does Python know where to locate gspread?  I tried looking in C:\python27 for clues but could not find anything related to gspread, not even in the `site-packages` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Python searches sys.path in order. It is likely that Python is importing gspread using the contents of the egg. Note that if Python finds a match before the gspread egg, it will stop on the first matching entry in sys.path. For example if you have a module named gspread in the current working directory, then Python will not use the egg.

If you want to modify the package, you have many different options. I suggest to first uninstall the current egg. Then place the folder named gspread in site-packages.

An even better alternative is to add the gspread source directory to PYTHONPATH. You can change the PYTHONPATH environment variable by

```
My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced > Environment Variables
```

Answer (score 0):

When you defined `--home` option setuptools is simulating linux Home directory thats why the installation location goes to X:\lib\python.

My guess is this home path is getting added to Python env on the system sorry I don't have windows to test this but there is some info here: https://docs.python.org/2.3/inst/alt-install-windows.html